# Rendering different event types in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok so i have 3 different classes (types of rl events)
Each event has different properties

Example is Swimming class that has temperature, PH value, swimming length and so on
next event is Cycling class that has Biketype, tyre width and so on

Now the events all have a date, and i want to render them sorted by date in a list.

Now each class has to be rendered differently according to the design, so im a little confused as to how i should solve this?

Was thinking about creating a list of objects and then passing ALL events of all types into the list
sort by date,,
then iterate through the list and based on what type of object i get, bind it to the usercontrol and render it..

is this is the best way to do this? or is there a simpler approach?

Comment: First of all is this homework?  Secondly, what do you mean by rendered, do you mean displayed on the screen, are you looking for a table view, like a datagridview, that will display all classes in chronological order?

Comment: Create an interface that all your classes implement that has a date property. You can then create a strongly typed list of that interface type to store them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a base class all the events derive from. This base class should have a `public virtual` method called `Render` and the `DateTime` field.

Derive all the event classes from that class and override the `Render` method, so that each event class can "render itself".

All you need to do is keep a list of instances of the base class ordered by time stamp and call `Render`.

Sample:

```
public class BaseEvent
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp;

    public virtual void Render() { }
}

public class Swimming : BaseEvent
{
    public override void Render()
    {
        // Code to render a Swimming instance
    }
}

public class Cycling: BaseEvent
{
    public override void Render()
    {
        // Code to render a Cycling instance
    }
}
```

The list to keep track of all events:

```
private List<BaseEvent> m_events;
```

Rendering all the events:

```
foreach (BaseEvent e in m_events)
    e.Render();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a good approach.

But try to avoid rendering the controls yourself. Add them to the Controls collection of a parent container control. Asp.net will render the controls itself that way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that has a dateTime in it then have other classes that are based on it.  Then you can create a list of the base class, and cast the objects to the extended class and use them.  Here is a working example

**Edit** Wow I confused myself with this, not sure how else to explain it so please ask for clarity, and I will do my best

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Sport> Sports = new List<Sport>();
        //create a swim object and give it some data
        Swimming swim1 = new Swimming();
        //create a cycle object and give it some data
        Cycling cycle1 = new Cycling();
        swim1.PH = 5;
        cycle1.BikeType = 2;
        // add the two objects to a list of base class
        Sports.Add(swim1);
        Sports.Add(cycle1);

        //iterate through the list of base class and cast the objects to their extended class
        //display a independent property of each just to prive it works.
        foreach (Sport s in Sports)
        {
            if (s is Cycling)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(((Cycling)s).BikeType.ToString());
            }
            else if (s is Swimming)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(((Swimming)s).PH.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}

class Sport
{
    DateTime DateAndTime = new DateTime();
}
class Swimming : Sport
{
    public int PH = 0;
    public int temperature = 0;
}
class Cycling : Sport
{
    public int BikeType = 1;
    public int TireSize = 26;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost like Thorsten Dittmar's solution but if you bind your list to a control such as GridView then you don't need to care about Render() method. Instead:

1) declare a new enum:

```
public enum EventType {Swimming, Cycling, etc}
```

2) pass enum value to base like in class declaration

```
public class Cycling: BaseEvent

    {
        public Cycling() : base(EventValue.Swimming)
    }
```

3) Add constructor to the BaseEvent, also add Event property

```
public class BaseEvent
{
    public BaseEvent(EventType type)
    {
        Event = type;
    }

    EventType Event { get; set; }
    DateTime EventDate ....
}
```

4) Then bind a list of type `List<BaseEvent>` to your control and in the OnItemDataBound event render whatever you want, based on the Event property value